# Is it possible to control which groups can a person be in LDAP?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm using OpenLDAP to store user data inside.
There's a group Workers (type groupOfNames), which consists of group Admins (type groupOfNames) and PowerUsers (type groupOfNames). I can assign user Bob to both Admins and PowerUsers.

Is there any way to restrict adding Bob to PowerUsers if he's already in group Admins (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 0):

In OpenLDAP (excluding developing custom code to alter the way OpenLDAP works) you can't add such controls.

This type of workflow is clearly in the scope of "managing the identities" and so it should be handled by your IDM solution.

OpenLDAP is just the solution to store what you represented in your IDM solution.

In the "IAM" stack you have [ IDM ] --> [ DS ] --> [ AM ] which stand for :

- IDentity Management : Here you handle how to create users, roles, groups, organization, etc.
- Directory Service (OpenLDAP here) : Here you store what you created in your IDM to deliver the data
- Access Management : Here you use the DS as a backend to authenticate, check authorizations, etc